# How to hide header for Contact iFrame source

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I am using an iFrame on a visual force page and I am using a URL parameter to hide the header. But I am getting an error `'Id value is not valid for the Contact standard controller'`

iFrame:

```
<apex:iframe src="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.View, Case.Contact.Id)}?isdtp=nv" scrolling="true"/>
```

This works without the `?isdtp=nv` parameter

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using `&isdtp=nv` instead of `?isdtp=nv`